# Using Wolfram Alpha-syntax for transpose, etc

Tags: matrix

Consider this expression:

```
{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}}*Transpose[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}}]
```

It returns an error in *Mathematica* but works perfectly fine in *Wolfram Alpha*.

Is there a way I can get *Mathematica* to recognize this syntax?  Why is there a difference between the ways that *Mathematica* and *Alpha* interpret this expression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short Version**

You can get *Mathematica* to convert *WolframAlpha*-style [free-form input](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWikflTjjJU) into a valid expression using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or by starting an input expression with <kbd>=</kbd>:

[image: expression input screenshot]

Note how *Mathematica* made sense of two alternative free-form expressions of the same thing, and converted each into the same valid expression involving the `Dot` operator.

---

**Longer Version:  Why is there a difference?**

*WolframAlpha* is primarily aimed at interpreting input from a human and delivering a response back to that human.  As such, it uses inference heavily to try to make sense of what the user entered.  In this case, *WolframAlpha* correctly inferred that the product operation in the expression is actually a matrix multiplication.  This is a very reasonable assumption given that WWW users might not be familiar with the ins and outs of *Mathematica* syntax.

In contrast, the *Mathematica* system serves two goals.  It shares the need to interact with a human just like *WolframAlpha*.  But it also allows *Mathematica* users (i.e. programmers) to write code intended to be executed by machine as part of larger composite systems.  In the first case, inferencing is welcomed as the user can immediately see whether the interpretation was correct.  In the second case, inferencing is harmful since there is no human in the loop to spot any misinterpretation.

*WolframAlpha* is treating the exhibited expression as free-form input.  The fact that it resembles an *Mathematica* expression is coincidental.  One gets the same result by entering, for example:

> ((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)) * Transpose ((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3))

This is *not* a valid *Mathematica* expression, yet *WolframAlpha* takes it in stride.

The good news is that *Mathematica* supports both use cases directly.  By starting an input expression with <kbd>=</kbd>, we can tell *Mathematica* that we want it to infer our meaning from free-form input:

[image: free-form input screenshot]

Note how the product operator has been quietly re-interpreted as the matrix-multiplying `Dot` operator.

Alternatively, we can use the unambiguous formal *Mathematica* syntax that makes no assumptions, reporting errors instead:

[image: expression input screenshot]

Here, *Mathematica* is not making any assumptions.  We specified `*` (`Times`), so it will attempt to use `*`.  It so happens that `Times` can be applied to matrices, meaning that the multiplication is to be threaded across matching numbers into the two matrices.  But... the two matrices do not have the same dimensions to the number cannot be matched up.  What is the error?  Are the matrix arguments wrong, or is the operator wrong?  *Mathematica* won't guess, so it reports an error to the user (programmer) to fix it.

Comment: In the course of routine maintenance I was preparing to delete this old, closed question, but I feel your answer has lasting value.  Would you consider improving the question to put this into the reopen queue?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I gave it a try.

Answer (score 5):

`Dot` is a special case of `Inner`

```
list = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}};

Inner[Times, list, Transpose[list], Plus] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}

Inner[Power, list, Transpose[list], Plus] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also possible:

```
Outer[Times, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for matrix multiplication, use `.` (or the `Dot` command).